# Android Program...coding Error

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I want to print A,B,C..... in series, but when I click the button it's Unfortunately stopped,

```
public class MainActivity extends ActionBarActivity {

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
                  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
                  setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final TextView alphabets = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.alphabet);
    Button next = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);
    View.OnClickListener listener = new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            String[] alpha= {"A","B","C" ,"D" ,"E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};
            int alp = alpha.length;
            for (int i=0;i<=alpha.length;i++)
            alphabets.setText(alpha[i]);
            }
    };

    next.setOnClickListener(listener);
```

Comment: your program will not print A,B,C....it will print only Z

Comment: @DroidMind - why is that?

Comment: @KevinDTimm See that it is the same textView set repeatedly                                            for (int i=0;i<=alpha.length;i++)
            alphabets.setText(alpha[i]);
            }

Comment: @DroidMind -Easy as pie - thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the reason is an `IndexOutOfBoundException` here:

```
 for (int i=0;i<=alpha.length;i++)
    alphabets.setText(alpha[i]);
 }
```

change it to

```
for (int i=0;i<alpha.length;i++)
    alphabets.setText(alpha[i]);
}
```

with your code you try to enter the last element +1 and that element does not exists.

btw. your `textview` will only display the last element!

EDIT:

```
String[] alpha= {"A","B","C" ,"D" ,"E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};
int alp = alpha.length;
StringBuffer alphabet = new StringBuffer();
for (int i=0;i<alpha.length;i++){
  alphabet.append(alpha[i]);
}
alphabets.setText(alphabet.toString());
```

Comment: Well, if you are going to put this in an answer you might aswell tell him how to properly show every alphabet in his textview.

Comment: Thanks a lot, but when i click the button its directly goes to "Z",not in series of b,c,d ,Thanks in Advance

Comment: @user3356684 - see comments in OP

Comment: it appends ABC,,,i want to print only a/b/c

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
String alpha[30];    
alpha= {"A","B","C" ,"D" ,"E","F","G","H","I","J","K","L","M","N","O","P","Q","R","S","T","U","V","W","X","Y","Z"};
```

Comment: This is not a complete answer.